# performing regex on dates.txt

Tags: python, regex

following data is a snippet from date.txt : https://github.com/BRAKESH3336/sample/blob/master/dates.txt

the task is to extract dates in format: 04/20/2009, 04/20/09, 4/20/09, 4/3/09

if the data is being imported as a single string the regex works

```py
df='''
03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):
6/18/85 Primary Care Doctor:
sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Services: None
7 on 9/27/75 Audit C Score Current:
2/6/96 sleep studyPain Treatment Pain Level (Numeric Scale): 7
.Per 7/06/79 Movement D/O note:
4, 5/18/78 Patient's thoughts about current substance abuse:
10/24/89 CPT Code: 90801 - Psychiatric Diagnosis Interview
3/7/86 SOS-10 Total Score:
(4/10/71)Score-1Audit C Score Current:
(5/11/85) Crt-1.96, BUN-26; AST/ALT-16/22; WBC_12.6Activities of Daily Living (ADL) Bathing: Independent
4/09/75 SOS-10 Total Score:
'''
pattern= re.compile(r'\d{0,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4}')
matches=pattern.finditer(df)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

however when the data is imported using open() the regex does not work

```py
doc = []
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        doc.append(line)

df = pd.Series(doc)
df.head(10)

pattern= re.compile(r'\d{0,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4}')
matches=pattern.finditer(df)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Why would that be ? The error that I get is :

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-c6639f3c12f4> in <module>
      1 pattern= re.compile(r'\d{0,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4}')
----> 2 matches=pattern.finditer(df)
      3 for match in matches:
      4     print(match)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: What is not working? What are you trying to do? What is the expected results and what is the actual result? Show some code and include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How for example do you apply the search on the dataframe?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you wish to achieve. Immediately before "this regex expression works:" you need some text such as, "I wish to match all substrings of `dt` that describe a date or a month and year <or whatever>, namely, the following:", to be followed by those strings you wish to match. Also, shorten the string `dt` as much as possible. Never say some code "doesn't work". Explain what it does that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory: The `finditer` method expects the second parameter to be a `string` or `bytes-like` object, but you are passing it an instance of `Series`. Since you have already read in the file as a string into the `doc` variable, your code should just be:

```
matches=pattern.finditer(''.join(doc))
```

Also, your regex really should be:

```
r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?'
```

1. `\d{1,2}` Matches 1 or 2 digits. You had `\d{0,2}` making the month optional (allowing a match of `/5/2020` for example), which is really not what you want.
2. `/` Matches a forward slash. No need to have `[/]` (although this is not wrong), which would be more useful if you wanted to allow multiple separators, e.g. `[/-]`.
3. `\d{1,2}` Matches 1 or 2 digits.
4. `/` Matches a forward slash.
5. `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` Matches 2 or 4 digits (matches 2 digits optionally followed by 2 more digits. This is more precise than what you had, which would have matched 2, 3, or 4 digits.

Also, the more "Pythonic" (and efficient) way to create a list of strings composed of each line in a text file would be:

```
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    doc = [line for line in file]
```

Is the use of `pandas` serving any purpose at this point? If not, then just read the entire file as a single string:

```
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    doc = file.read()
```

And then there is no need to do any joining of lines later on.

Comment: matches=pattern.finditer(doc)  does not work. Error -> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: using df.str.extractall(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?') yields error too. ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Comment: I am sorry about that. I forgot that `doc` was a list of strings rather than a single string. So the elements of the list needed to first be `join`ed together. I have updated the answer.